# Get-Disk and Get-PhysicalDisk return different results

Tags: powershell, storage, storage-spaces

I am trying to set up storage spaces on Windows 10 Pro, but I am confused by the output of Get-Disk and Get-PhysicalDisk:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PhysicalDisk | select DeviceId,friendlyname,serialnumber,canpool

DeviceId friendlyname              serialnumber         canpool
-------- ------------              ------------         -------
2        Samsung SSD 980 PRO 500GB 0025_38BB_0152_4B00.   False
1        Samsung SSD 980 PRO 500GB 0025_38BB_0152_4B51.   False
0        Samsung SSD 870 QVO 2TB   S5SUNF0R209736R        False


PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Disk | select Number,friendlyname,serialnumber

Number friendlyname              serialnumber
------ ------------              ------------
     1 Samsung SSD 980 PRO 500GB 0025_38BB_0152_4B51.
```

What I am really trying to achieve is to create a tiered storage pool with disks 0 and 2, using 2 as a cache.

It seems the problem is that these physical disks are not recognized as "logical disks" (if that is a term).  I have tried to Initialize-Disk (which is supposed to initialize a partition table) which can't find the disk by number:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Initialize-Disk -Number 0
Initialize-Disk : No MSFT_Disk objects found with property 'Number' equal to '0'.
```

And I have tried Reset-PhysicalDisk which does nothing to the list returned by Get-Disk.

So, two questions which I think is related:

- how can I enable a physical disk to be "CanPool"?
- how can I get disks listed from Get-PhysicalDisk to show up in Get-Disk?

Comment: Were they converted to dynamic disks?

Comment: I don't know, how do I check? And what does that mean? Do I want them do be dynamic?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk

Comment: Thank you. This describes using DISKPART and "list disk", but this gives me the same output as Get-Disk, it doesn't show disk 0 or 2, only disk 1 (which is not dynamic, by the way).

Comment: How do your Device Manager and Disk Managment look?

Comment: Device Manager show all 3, Disk Manager only disk 1. In desperation, I tried rebooting, still the same :-(

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is simply `Get-Disk` is logical disks only, and `Get-PhysicalDisk` returns the attached disk devices, but it looks like you know this.

`Get-PhysicalDisk` actually has a `CannotPoolReason` property which may be helpful to you:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | Select DeviceID,CanPool,CannotPoolReason

deviceid canpool CannotPoolReason     
-------- ------- ----------------     
0          False Insufficient Capacity
2          False Insufficient Capacity
1          False Insufficient Capacity
```

Disks to be used in a storage pool must have no partition present (and therefore should not show up in `Get-Disk` *and* should not be initialized). Check with:

```
Get-Partition -DiskNumber 0,2
```

If you have any partitions listed, or if you have initialized the disks, use `Reset-PhysicalDisk` to fix. Note that this **wipes all data on the disk**, so be careful. Sometimes you may have to rescan for disks (or restart the machine) to get them to have `CanPool` set correctly.

Finally, once your disks can pool, you can create your storage pool. This is just an example, so change the values to suit your needs.

```
$PhysicalDisks = Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $True

# Create the pool
New-StoragePool -FriendlyName "Data" -StorageSubsystemFriendlyName "MyStorage*" -PhysicalDisks $PhysicalDisks | 

    # And, optionally create a partition within your pool to use:
    New-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName "UserData" -Size 100GB -ProvisioningType Thin | 
    Initialize-Disk -PassThru | 
    New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | 
    Format-Volume
```

Storage spaces automatically uses your fastest tier of hard drive for caching. Good luck!

[edit] looks like you found an answer seconds before me :^)

Comment: Ok, thank you. My own answer was really unsatisfactory, as it involved booting to linux and removing everything. Anyway, quick follow-up question: do you know if it is possible to boot from a Virtual Disk on a Storage Pool? (I am guessing that the UEFI-BIOS can't handle the storage pool, but what if I put the EFI system partition on a separate disk?)

Comment: @RolfRander Technically, yes. This is how the new Surface Pro tablets come now, but it may be a surface-bios thing and not necessarily UEFI-compliant. I would not recommend it except for curiosity's sake. Check it out: https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2017/10/boot-from-storage-spaces-virtual-disk-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out.

I rebooted from a linux live-USB to take a look at the partition table, and it turned out that the two disks were already partitioned for Storage Spaces. I had opened the GUI for storage spaces and decided that it didn't have the features I want (tiering), but apparently it had already partitioned the drives for storage spaces, and this made them unavailable for all other operations.

I even started reinstalling, but only one disk was available.

It is possible that I could have undone this using storage space management in either the control panel or powershell, but by this time the partitions had already been destroyed in my reinstallation attemt.